# What does `return 1 + strlen_rec(&arr[1]) ;` mean?

Tags: c, return

I have some code:

```
int strlen_rec(char arr[])
{

    if(arr[0]=='\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + strlen_rec(&arr[1]) ;
}
```

The line

```
return 1 + strlen_rec(&arr[1]) ;
```

is confusing me. Can someone explain what it does?

Comment: read about recursion.

Comment: And try using a debugger to step through the code line by line.

Comment: There's no question here!!!

Comment: When reading about recursion, also pay attention to the additional overhead required by each successive function call as part of the recursion, and the advise to avoid recursion unless a procedural solution is prohibitive. There is nothing wrong with recursion and it can solve some interesting problems -- that said, be mindful it comes with additional baggage.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Reading "between the lines" here, I would tend to guess that OP needs to focus on the basics before jumping to efficiency-related considerations.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the sentiment, but as long as he was going to do a bit of reading about recursion, he might as well read that part as well `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function counts the length of a string using recursion. It may look confusing since it's using an array like a pointer. `&ar[1]` is increasing the pointer (calling the function with the address of the next byte). C strings are terminated with a null byte which isn't included in the length so it returns 0 when reached.